# refresh datetimepicker after selecting date javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When I select a date in the calendar it does not refresh the textbox:

```html
<div class="input-group"> 
  <asp:TextBox ID="datePEC" runat="server" 
               CssClass="form-control" Width="250px" Height="30px"  
               AutoPostBack="true" /> 
</div>
```

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[name="ctl00$MainContent$datePEC"]').daterangepicker({
                "singleDatePicker": true,
                "timePicker": true,
                "timePicker24Hour": true,
                "locale": {
                    "format": "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", "separator": " - ", "applyLabel": "Valider",
        "cancelLabel": "Annuler","fromLabel": "Du", "toLabel": "Au","customRangeLabel":    "Custom","weekLabel": "S",
                    "daysOfWeek": ["Di","Lu","Ma","Me","Je","Ve","Sa"],
                    "monthNames": ["Janvier","Février","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Juillet",
                        "Aout","Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Décembre" ],
                    "firstDay": 1
                }, opens: 'left'
            }, function (start, end, label) {
                    console.log(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm') );
            });
```

Comment: can you please share the html code also?

Comment: hi kavi a working with asp.net

Comment: <div class="input-group">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="datePEC" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" Width="250px" Height="30px" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                          
                                        </div>

Comment: share the datepicker part code from asp.net

Comment: i share in question

Comment: Recall that the TextBox control's ID